# Trouble accessing Ubuntu vm in google cloud with Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-machine, desktop

Following [these instructions](https://ubuntu.com/blog/launch-ubuntu-desktop-on-google-cloud), I have done the following:

- created a vm on google cloud compute using Ubuntu Pro
- installed a desktop environment
- installed the google chrome remote desktop
- tried to connect to the desktop from my google chrome browser

Everything went as per the instructions until I saw this screen which I cannot get past:
[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGJWM.png)

I am not aware that I have a password; when I connect to my vm using the SSH link on google cloud, I am never prompted for one. I tried explicitly setting a password using passwd, but that didn't help.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to your VM in ssh without password, it's because it's a link on google cloud. Certainly with a key.
In my opinion, test the ssh connection from your local computer.
If you're asked a password, recreate your vm being careful to indicate a password.
keep me posted on progress
bye

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it a different way: I installed a different desktop environment, Xfce, and then it didn't present me with a password dialog when logging in from chrome remote desktop.